# Gridview is not working properly Edit command will not fire

Tags: c#, asp.net

When we click an Edit command on gridview sometimes it fire and sometimes not when page change (go to next page),sometimes go to another method and sometimes it is unchecked data which is binding on gridview.
I am annoying this problem last 2 days Please any one have solution then Help me .
Thanks a lot

```
     <div class="panel-body ">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <asp:GridView Width="100%" GridLines="None" PagerSettings-Visible="false" ShowHeader="true"
                        runat="server" ID="grdcontrl" AutoGenerateColumns="false" class="table table-bordered table-hover panel-primary table-striped "
                        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="tr2" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowCommand="grdcontrl_RowCommand" HeaderStyle-CssClass="panel-heading" OnRowDeleting="grdcontrl_RowDeleting">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="tr2" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PID">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:Label ID="lblId" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %> ' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                   <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("ParentsID") %> ' Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>

                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblView" Text='<%# Eval("ControlToDisplay") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>

                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="LblLabel" Text='<%# Eval("FieldLabel") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>

                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:Label ID="lblChechbx" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %> ' Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="ckActv" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("IsActive") %>' OnCheckedChanged="ckActv_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
                                </ItemTemplate>

                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date of Birth">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:Label ID="lblOptnVal" Text='<%# Eval("OptionValue") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>

                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="edit" runat="server" CommandName="editts" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ImageUrl="../Content/themes/images/user_edit.png" />
                                  <%--  <asp:ImageButton ID="imgEditPatient" runat="server" CommandName="EditDetails" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ImageUrl="../Content/themes/images/user_edit.png" ToolTip="Edit" />
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDeletePatient" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteDetails" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ImageUrl="../Content/themes/images/Delete.png" Height="16px" Width="16px" ToolTip="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?.');" />
                                   --%>
                                </ItemTemplate>

                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="panel-heading" />
                        <PagerSettings Visible="False" PageButtonCount="999999" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Post the `OnRowCommand` Code behind code as well

Comment: if (e.CommandName == "editts")
            {
                Response.Redirect("AddControl.aspx?ID=" + e.CommandArgument);
            }

Comment: Do you have an update panel on the page or the master page?

Comment: Sorry,yes it is under an update panel ( i m getting annoying this problem)

Comment: try commenting out the update panel if its not needed and see if it works properly,incase you require the update panel  then use trigger  for it to work.

Comment: Already i m using trigger in it

Comment: Just comment out the update panel and check once

Comment: Not working ....when i comment and click the edit it doesn't do anything

Comment: Use F12 in chrome to try and debug it, and see whats the error that is coming

Answer (score 0):

use [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408(v=vs.110).aspx) navigate page in UpdatePanel

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "navigate", "location.href = 'SomePage.aspx'", true);
```

Comment: I m using linkButton in the place of imagebutton then it worked but one problem is come back which is when i edit and come back to the grid list it automatic goew on the method of checkbox change and change it why?